# rostipic echo doesn't work because of a md5sum problem

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am playing a bag file and I typed rostopic echo /nav_status to see the actual messages but this error message appears. What's going on? I saw other similar questions but I don't understand them. Thanks

```
 [ERROR] [1638128325.171514535]: Client [/rostopic_4147_1638128309790] wants topic /nav_status to have datatype/md5sum [marta_msgs/NavStatus/ccb836e840c83634382508157bfdb91e], but our version has [marta_msgs/NavStatus/2652576ed189854bff45893603a05bc0]. Dropping connection.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391766/rostipic-echo-doesn%27t-work-because-of-a-md5sum-problem/) by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2021-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the data in the bag file used one version of the `marta_msgs/NavStatus` message type, and your system has a different version installed. You probably need to install an older version of the package that provides `marta_msgs`. You tagged this with `kinetic` so I assume you are using ROS Kinetic. If you know what version of ROS the bag file was created on, you can find the version of the package that is for that ROS version. Then you can copy out the message definition file and install it locally.

To solve the problem more permanently for this bag file, you could writer a converter that takes in the old message type on one topic, and publishes the new type on a new topic, and play the bag file into that while recording the output into a new bag file.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0